# Solving Ax = b , CUDA vs Matlab

Tags: matlab, cuda, linear-equation

I've done the following test on Matlab:

```
n = 10000;
A = rand(n,n);
b = rand(n, 1);

tic
y = A\b;
toc
```

On my Intel i7 gen 5 machine (12 cores) the result is ~ 5 seconds.

Then, I've trying to do the same using CUDA 9.2 sample SDK code (see cuSolverDn_LinearSolver.cpp). Surprisingly, on my Nvidia 970GTX I get ~ 6.5 seconds to get the solution for the same problem size as above!

What is it wrong ? I mention that my matrix is symmetric, square and b has only 1 column. Is there a better way to solve this problem using CUDA? Should I expect greater performance if I'm going to use a newer GPU?

Comment: How can `A = rand(n,n);` yield a symmetric matrix, as you claim in your question?

Comment: Have you performed the experiment in single or double precision? A 12 core i7 is quite a beefy machine by the way.

Comment: Try using Matlabs gpu funcionality and see how fast that is. If it is faster than the cpu code then you can certainly do better, if not, the benefit is perhaps countered by the overhead

Comment: In cpp i made it symmetric, not in matlab. I’m using doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used to test this

```
n = 10000;
A = rand(n,n,'single');
b = rand(n, 1,'single');

tic
y = A\b;
toc

A = gpuArray(A);
b = gpuArray(b);

tic
y = A\b;
toc
```

Here are the results

```
Elapsed time is 2.673490 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.553348 seconds.
```

I am running on a 7700 4 core laptop with a GTX 1060 GPU so approximately the same computing power I think. As you can see in this case the GPU runs faster. The most likely factor is the precision. GPUs only have single precision multipliers while CPUs have double precision multipliers. If you have to do double precision multiplication on a GPU you have to take quite a few multipliers to do the same operation thus drastically slowing down your speed. If I change it so the variables are double precision we now get:

```
Elapsed time is 5.784525 seconds.
Elapsed time is 5.398702 seconds.
```

While the GPU is still faster on my computer the point still stands in that the CPU and GPU are much closer together now.

Comment: Interesting to see `double` being half as fast as `single`on CPU. That points at the bottleneck being data transfer from memory to CPU, because the CPU does single float computations using the same representation as double floats (usually 10 bytes, long double, for modern CPUs).

Comment: I know, I was surprised by that too. Thing is the data transfer should be a much smaller fraction since it's only 10000 values. Are we sure modern CPUs don't have single precision cores are they all double precision?

Comment: SSE/AVX vector units will compute twice as many floats per cycle as doubles.  This is probably what is used at the optimized BLAS level behind these operations

Comment: It is `10000 * 10000` values, that is more than fits in your cache. I am not 100% sure about the CPU not having a single-precision core. As @Peter mentions, there are SIMD instructions that logically can process twice as many single-precision floats as double-precision floats. But I'm not sure how much those are used here.

Comment: "GPUs only have single precision multipliers":  Since the Fermi architecture (ca. 10 years ago) all NVIDIA GPUs have included double-precision arithmetic units. However, the throughput of double-precision operations is only 1/2 to 1/64 of the single-precision operations, with consumer GPUs (such as the asker's GPU) at the low-end of the spectrum.

Comment: MATLAB uses the Intel MKL for its BLAS (and LAPACK) implementation, which most certainly uses the highest-supported vector instruction set.